# Should we follow this method in company's Web development Team also , seperation of Content , presentation and behaviour?

Tags: css, xhtml, web-standards

as

Content = Content Builder ( Who will convert Client's Content (MS Word files) into XHTML

Presentation = CSS Experts

Behaviour = Javascript , jquery experts.

but where is design. Is Presentation = Design or Presentation = CSS only ?

Edit:

Like Should we hire one person to make Design, XHTML, CSS and Javascript or different person for each thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that. If you are lucky you can find someone that have skills in all of those. But that also depends on the workload etc. What you could do is maybe split it in 2 roles. One person that makes the design and one that does the html/css/javascript. But it so depends on what people you find!

Comment: +1 good reply . Should i suggest to XHTML CSS to learn javascript or Should i suggest to Designer to learn XHTML and CSS?